# Spring boot post api - org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "password" violates not-null constraint

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot

I have created a spring boot application. And in the application I'm working with API's. I have an POST API for creating an user, but every time I use the api, i will get the following error

```
Spring boot post api - org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "password" violates not-null constraint
```

Im using hibernate and PostgreSQL as database.

Even if I give de data values, i will get this error. I searched over the internet, but I cant find a solution for this problem

This is the code that i user:

Users.java:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@ToString
@Table
public class Users {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int user_id;
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String username;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;
}
```

UsersRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface UsersRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, Integer> {}
```

UsersService

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Transactional
public class UsersService {
    private final UsersRepository usersRepository;

    public Users createUser(Users newUsers) {
        return this.usersRepository.save(newUsers);
    }
}
```

UsersDto

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UsersDto {
    private int user_id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
}
```

UsersMapper

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public interface UsersMapper {
    UsersDto toDto(Users users);
    Users toModel(UsersDto usersDto);
}
```

UsersController

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/users")
@Validated
public class UsersController {
    private final UsersService usersService;
    private final UsersMapper usersMapper;

    @PostMapping()
    @ApiOperation(value = "Create new user", httpMethod = "POST", code = 201)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<UsersDto> createUser(@RequestBody UsersDto usersDto) throws Exception {
        Users users = this.usersMapper.toModel(usersDto);
        Users createUsers = this.usersService.createUser(users);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(this.usersMapper.toDto(createUsers));
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me with this problem

Comment: can you debug and check if  this.usersMapper.toModel(usersDto) is actually return the right users object?

Comment: Does `UsersDto toDto(Users users);` work?

Comment: @JeannotMn i have debugged the this.usersMapper.toModel(usersDto), and it dont return the users object. I see that the username and password both are null

Comment: Do you have the value on the usersDto?

Comment: @JeannotMn the value i get from the usersdto, is this: Users(user_id= 0, username=null, password= null)

Comment: How are you then calling your backend? Seems that the problem is from the client app

Comment: Im calling it from the swagger page

Answer (score 0):

The error says that the password is null, what is not allowed. So it's probably not provided on the request send to your API. You could add validation constraints to the endpoint, like

```
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class UsersDto {
        private int user_id;
        @NotNull
        private String username;
        @NotNull
        private String password;
    }
```

One more note, storing password as plain text is **not advised** , it's a major security issue. You should create and use a hash instead, check out Spring Security for this.

PS - check out bootify.io - here you can create your REST API together with the validation constraints.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your controller, and check what you receive in debug mode. Probably password is null, so you need to find out why.

Comment: I debugged the controller and the mapper, if i send the usersDto to this.usersMapper.toModel(usersDto), it will send back the values with null

Comment: So something with the @Mapper is not working - I'm not so familiar with MapStruct to understand the issue.

Comment: I have found an alternative solution. Instead of doing it through the Mapper, I do it through the ModelMapper